# Windows 8.1 cannot display some words normally in system applications

Tags: windows-8.1, fonts

[image]

As you can see from the image the title of the window cannot be displayed normally.
I think it's an error caused by the font. I can snap the text, which is "再接続しています", by SnagIt, and I can also see the text in the mstscax.dll.mui file by Resource Hacker.

Answer (score 0):

It says "Connection failed, Network not available, when available a newattempt at connecting will initialize"
I assume you have some problem with your router.

Comment: plz read questions carefully. i kno japanese

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally solved the problem with the help of a friend of mine.

The method is: Change the encoding of the system to another one, and then turn back to Japanese.

It's said that these kinds of problems are often caused by Font Link of Windows. So just reset  the cache by changing encoding.